# MySQL Nested Blocks Error 1064

Tags: mysql, delimiter

Can anyone see why I would get:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '//

DELIMITER' at line 11
```

For the following snippet:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE 
IF EXISTS nested_test//
CREATE PROCEDURE nested_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT;
    SET a = 1;
    SELECT a;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE b INT;
        SET b = 2;
        SELECT b;
    END;
END//

DELIMITER;
```

This is a simplified version of what I am actually writing and it brings up exactly the same error. Everything is great until I add the nested BEGIN END block. It works perfectly well on phpMyAdmin but fails on Navicat 9

Answer (score 0):

It should have a space after `DELIMITER`.

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Like that.

---

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE 
IF EXISTS nested_test//
CREATE PROCEDURE nested_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT;
    SET a = 1;
    SELECT a;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE b INT;
        SET b = 2;
        SELECT b;
     END;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

On execution, it generates:

> 0 rows affected, 0 rows found. Duration for 2 queries: 0.000 sec.

Comment: This fails on my system, MySQL v. 5.1.68 using Navicat v9